# Can't acquire FCM registration token

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the FCM registration token or the device token in short to send push notifications to my application from my server.

The thing is I tried to get it like the code shown below but nothing happens even after uninstalling and reinstalling the apps. I'm already made sure that my Tag manager is working and also all the services needed already set in `AndroidManifests.xml`.

For information, I already test the Push Notifications from the firebase site and it's working just fine. But that's not what I'm aiming for. I don't understand why I can send the notifications from Firebase but can't see/acquire the FCM registration token on my Android Studio console. Is there something I missed here. I'm a beginner in this kind of thing and have been stucked with this problem for about 1 week already and at my wits end here. Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
public class FirebaseIDService  extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIdService";
    public String tok;

   @Override
   public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
       String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
       // Instance ID token to your app server.

       //sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
   }

   private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
   }
}
```

AndroidManifests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.asii_developer.asiisupport">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/planete"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/planete"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <!--
        <service
            android:name=".DeviceToken">
            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".PageBienvenueActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PagedAccueilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FormActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RecapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PageDeConnexion" />
        <activity android:name=".mot_de_passeActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Liste_des_ticketsActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ConversationActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".NotificationsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="notifActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.Firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.Firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>

        </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFireBaseMessagingService.xml

```
package com.example.asii_developer.asiisupport;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override

    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.arrow)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Implement this method to send token to your app's server
       sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }
// [END refresh_token]
```

And one more thing:

> You need to call sendRegistrationToServer() method which will update
>   token on server, if you are sending push notifications from server.

**NOTE:**

New Firebase token is generated (onTokenRefresh() is called) when:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- Theuser uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: I know very well when the token is generated that's why i tried to uninstall and reinstall the apps countless of times already..my main objective right now is to print the token on Android Studio console before sending it to the server

Comment: After reinstalling the app, try my code again. You should see the token on the phone now. If you don't, please let me know! Also, what is the value of token when it is logged? Is it null or is it empty?

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work..it gives me null when logged

Comment: Are you sure you added                                                                                 `<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>`                                                                                               
in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) first (probably in your `MainActivity` or any corresponding initial activity.

`onTokenRefresh()` only triggers later in the beginning **if and only if** the initial call to `FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()` return null. As mentioned in the [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register):

> The onTokenRefreshcallback fires whenever a new token is generated, so calling getToken in its context ensures that you are accessing a current, available registration token. FirebaseInstanceID.getToken() returns null if the token has not yet been generated.